# String parsing with multiple delimeters

Tags: python, strings, parsing, unicode

My data is in this format:

> 龍舟 龙舟 [long2 zhou1] /dragon boat/imperial boat/\n

And I want to return:

```
('龍舟', '龙舟', 'long2 zhou1', '/dragon boat/imperial boat/')
```

In C I could do this in one line with `sscanf`, but I seem to be  f̶a̶i̶l̶i̶n̶g̶ writing code like a schoolkid with Python:

```
    working = line.rstrip().split(" ")
    trad, simp = working[0], working[1]
    working = " ".join(working[2:]).split("]")
    pinyin = working[0][1:]
    english = working[1][1:]
    return trad, simp, pinyin, english
```

Can I improve?

Comment: This is a little hard to parse because the logical field separator, the space character, is also a valid character inside the last two fields. This is disambiguated with brackets and slashes, but that obviously make the parse harder and uglier.

Comment: If your code doesn't work correctly, then this question is off topic here. See the [FAQ].

Comment: @svick it works perfectly - by "failing" I meant "failing to write neat code"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) with [re](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/re.html) module. For example the following regular expression works with binary strings and Unicode string (I'm not sure which version of Python you use).

For Python 2.7.3:

```
>>> s = "龍舟 龙舟 [long2 zhou1] /dragon boat/imperial boat/\n"
>>> u = s.decode("utf-8")
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r"^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) \[([^]]+)\] (.+)", s).groups()
('\xe9\xbe\x8d\xe8\x88\x9f', '\xe9\xbe\x99\xe8\x88\x9f', 'long2 zhou1', '/dragon boat/imperial boat/')
>>> re.match(r"^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) \[([^]]+)\] (.+)", u).groups()
(u'\u9f8d\u821f', u'\u9f99\u821f', u'long2 zhou1', u'/dragon boat/imperial boat/')
```

For Python 3.2.3:

```
>>> s = "龍舟 龙舟 [long2 zhou1] /dragon boat/imperial boat/\n"
>>> b = s.encode("utf-8")
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r"^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) \[([^]]+)\] (.+)", s).groups()
('龍舟', '龙舟', 'long2 zhou1', '/dragon boat/imperial boat/')
>>> re.match(br"^([^ ]+) ([^ ]+) \[([^]]+)\] (.+)", b).groups()
(b'\xe9\xbe\x8d\xe8\x88\x9f', b'\xe9\xbe\x99\xe8\x88\x9f', b'long2 zhou1', b'/dragon boat/imperial boat/')
```

Comment: `groups()` and `groupdict()` are great!

Answer (score 2):

My goal here is clarity above all else. I think a first step is to use the `maxsplit` argument of [`split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to get the first two pieces and the remainder:

```
trad, simp, remainder = line.rstrip().split(' ', 2)
```

Now, to parse the leftovers I'm afraid I only see slightly ugly choices. Some people like regular expressions and others hate them. Without regular expressions, I think it's easiest to view the remainder as two field separated with `"] "`

```
pinyin, english = remainder.split("] ")
pinyin = pinyin[1:] # get rid of leading '['
```

Answer (score 0):

I would split around the square brackets first

```
def parse_string(s):
    a, b = s.rstrip().split(' [', 2)
    return a.split(' ') + b.split('] ', 2)
```

or more explicitly

```
def parse_string(s):
    first, rest = s.rstrip().split(' [', 2)
    trad, simp = first.split(' ', 2)
    pinyin, english = rest.split('] ', 2)
    return trad, simp, pinyin, english
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps try using the [parse](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/parse) module, which you need to download from [pypi](http://pypi.python.org). It's intended to function in the opposite manner from the `format` method.

```
>>> import parse
>>> data = "龍舟 龙舟 [long2 zhou1] /dragon boat/imperial boat/\n"
>>> match = "{} {} [{}] {}\n"
>>> result = parse.parse(match, data)
>>> print result
<Result ('龍舟', '龙舟', 'long2 zhou1', '/dragon boat/imperial boat/') {}>
>>> print result[0] 
'龍舟'
```

If you want to be able to access the result as a dictionary, you could name each of the parameters inside the brackets:

```
>>> import parse
>>> data = "龍舟 龙舟 [long2 zhou1] /dragon boat/imperial boat/\n"
>>> match = "{trad} {simp} [{pinyin}] {english}\n"
>>> result = parse.parse(match, data)
>>> print result
<Result () {'english': '/dragon boat/imperial boat/', 'trad': '龍舟', 'simp': '龙舟', 'pinyin': 'long2 zhou1'}>
>>> print result['trad'] 
'龍舟'
```

Comment: Is there some way to specify that the first two groups shouldn't contain spaces? Because I think unexpected input should cause an error, not silently return unexpected results.